# Why do I need to use MapView instead of standard browser?

Tags: android, browser, android-mapview

What can be the reason to use MapView in my application? Why can not I just pass the url to standard user's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map view is useful when you want to show custom data or views.

It also gives you more control and more importantly keeps the user within the application which is good in terms of user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add custom layers of icons, interaction, touch events etc...